# Bind method in Tkinter passes an argument when it shouldn't

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

I'm creating an interface in Python using Tkinter, which consists of a few text entry boxes and a button which has a callback function to process the data that has been entered. In order to improve the user experience, I wanted to make it so that in addition to being able to click the button, the user could also press the return key while focused on any of the text entry boxes to submit their data.

I tried using the 'bind' method on each of the entry widgets, supplying the key code for return as the first argument and the name of the callback function as the second, but for some reason I'm getting an exception because it says the function expects no argument but is being given 1. Why is this binding giving an argument to the function, and is there any way I can prevent this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binded callback called with event object.
callback registered with `(command=...)` style called without argument.

If you want to bind callback with both style, callback should look like follow:

```
def callback(event=None):
    ...
```

Comment: Using that keyword argument in my callback worked a charm, thanks!